# c# microsoft.graph SDK copy message to another mailbox

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to copy a sent message from the users mailbox into a shared mailbox folder.

I'm creating an email as a draft to get it's id.

```
Message SavedMessage = await service.Create(client, message);
```

Then sending with that Id. Which works fine.

```
await service.SendEmailByMessageId(client, SavedMessage.Id, model.From);
```

Then I need to copy that sent email to another mailbox.
The trouble I'm having is when I retrieve this email and save to the other mailbox it's retrieved as a new message and then saved as a draft.

I've tried using the copy method but can't work out how to copy to another mailbox. Copying to another folder in same mailbox works with.

```
await UserBuilder.Messages[messageId].Copy(destinationId).Request().PostAsync();
```

Anyone able to help ?

Update:

Tried to change IsDraft flag but getting error.
Code: RequestBodyRead
Message: The property 'responseHeaders' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Message'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type.

Code using is:

```
Message MovedMessage = await Client.Users[crmArchiveId.Id].Messages[newMessage.Id].Move("Archive").Request().PostAsync();

MovedMessage.IsDraft = false;

return await Update(client, MovedMessage.Id, MovedMessage, "archiveuser");

public async Task<Message> Update(GraphServiceClient client, string id, Message message, string userId = null)
    {
        IUserRequestBuilder userBuilder = userId == null ? client.Me : client.Users[userId];
        return await userBuilder.Messages[id].Request().UpdateAsync(message);
    }
```

Comment: Where did you get the client library? Is this from the Connected Services experience from within Visual Studio?

Comment: From https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph
I'm using v1.9.0.0

Comment: @Marc LaFleur are you able to help me ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to copy an item with its state intact to a new mailbox with the Graph API. If the only issue is the isDraft flag, then you may be able to use extended properties to set the isDraft flag. You may have to set it **after** you've saved it to the other mailbox.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee160304(v=exchg.80).aspx

At this time, you can create a new message in the *to mailbox* using property values on the target message in the *from mailbox*.

Comment: Thanks Micahel. I'm getting an error trying to change the flag. I've updated question.

Comment: Use [Microsoft Graph UserVoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) to request this feature.

Comment: Here's a [direct link](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/39627928-message-copy-allow-to-copy-message-to-another-mai) to the open request.